# Swap items in doubly-linked list by their indices in the backing array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, swap, doubly-linked-list

I have an array of objects of the following type:

```
struct Node {
    Node *_pPrev, *_pNext;
    double *_pData;
};
```

Some of the nodes participate in a doubly-linked list, with `_pData!=nullptr` for such nodes. There is also a dummy head node with `_pNext` pointing to the beginning of the list, and `_pPrev` pointing to the end. The list starts with containing only this head node, and it should be never removed from the list.

The doubly-linked list is backed by an array, with initial size equal to the maximum number of nodes in the list.

```
struct Example {
    Node _nodes[MAXN];
    Node _head;
};
```

Now I want to perform the following operation on this data structure: given 2 indices `i` and `j` to the `_nodes` array, swap the nodes in the array, but preserve their positions in the doubly-linked list. This operation needs updating `_nodes[i]._pPrev->_pNext`, `_nodes[i]._pNext->_pPrev` and the same for node `j`.

One problem is the corner cases when nodes `i` and `j` are next to each other. Another problem is that the naive code involves a lot of `if`s (to check for `_pData==nullptr` for each node and handle the 3 cases differently, and to check whether the nodes are next to each other), thus becoming inefficient.

How to do it efficiently?

Here is what I have so far in C++:

```
assert(i!=j);
Node &chI = _nodes[i];
Node &chJ = _nodes[j];
switch (((chI._pData == nullptr) ? 0 : 1) | ((chJ._pData == nullptr) ? 0 : 2)) {
case 3:
    if (chI._pNext == &chJ) {
        chI._pPrev->_pNext = &chJ;
        chJ._pNext->_pPrev = &chI;
        chI._pNext = &chI;
        chJ._pPrev = &chJ;
    }
    else if (chJ._pNext == &chI) {
        chJ._pPrev->_pNext = &chI;
        chI._pNext->_pPrev = &chJ;
        chJ._pNext = &chJ;
        chI._pPrev = &chI;
    } else {
        chI._pNext->_pPrev = &chJ;
        chJ._pNext->_pPrev = &chI;
        chI._pPrev->_pNext = &chJ;
        chJ._pPrev->_pNext = &chI;
    }
    break;
case 2:
    chJ._pNext->_pPrev = &chI;
    chJ._pPrev->_pNext = &chI;
    break;
case 1:
    chI._pNext->_pPrev = &chJ;
    chI._pPrev->_pNext = &chJ;
    break;
default:
    return; // no need to swap because both are not in the doubly-linked list
}
std::swap(chI, chJ);
```

Comment: `but preserve their positions in the doubly-linked list.` -->> `This operation needs updating _nodes[i]._pPrev->_pNext, _nodes[i]._pNext->_pPrev` does not compute. If the opsition in the LL is unchanged the .prev and .next pointers are unchanged. Ergo: just memcopy over a temp. (and backpatch the incoming pointers)

Comment: @wildplasser, I mean that if item pointing to `pData1` was k-th from the head in the linked-list before the swap, it should stay k-th from the head after the swap too. So the item changes its ordinal position in the array, but not in the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

- The node contents of two nodes can be swapped, without changing their meaning; only their addresses will change
- since the addresses have changed, **all** references to the two nodes must change, too, including pointers **inside** the nodes that happen to point to one of the two nodes.

Here is an illustration of the swap first & fixup later (TM) method. Its major feat is that it avoids all the corner cases. It does assume a well-formed LL , and it ignores the "in_use" condition (which IMHO is orthogonal to the LL-swap-problem)

Note I did a bit of renaming, added test data, and converted to Pure C.

---

EDITED (now it actually works!)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    struct Node *prev, *next;
    // double *_pData;
    int val;
        };

#define MAXN 5
struct Example {
    struct Node head;
    struct Node nodes[MAXN];
        };

        /* sample data */
struct Example example = {
        { &example.nodes[4] , &example.nodes[0] , -1} // Head
        ,{ { &example.head , &example.nodes[1] , 0}
        , { &example.nodes[0] , &example.nodes[2] , 1}
        , { &example.nodes[1] , &example.nodes[3] , 2}
        , { &example.nodes[2] , &example.nodes[4] , 3}
        , { &example.nodes[3] , &example.head , 4}
        }
        };

void swapit( unsigned one, unsigned two)
{
struct Node tmp, *ptr1, *ptr2;
        /* *unique* array of pointers-to pointer
         * to fixup all the references to the two moved nodes
         */
struct Node **fixlist[8];
unsigned nfix = 0;
unsigned ifix;

        /* Ugly macro to add entries to the list of fixups */

#define add_fixup(pp) fixlist[nfix++] = (pp)

ptr1 = &example.nodes[one];
ptr2 = &example.nodes[two];

        /* Add pointers to some of the 8 possible pointers to the fixup-array.
        ** If the {prev,next} pointers do not point to {ptr1,ptr2}
        ** we do NOT need to fix them up.
        */
if (ptr1->next == ptr2) add_fixup(&ptr2->next); // need &ptr2->next here (instead of ptr1)
else    add_fixup(&ptr1->next->prev);
if (ptr1->prev == ptr2) add_fixup(&ptr2->prev); // , because pointer swap takes place AFTER the object swap
else    add_fixup(&ptr1->prev->next);
if (ptr2->next == ptr1) add_fixup(&ptr1->next);
else    add_fixup(&ptr2->next->prev);
if (ptr2->prev == ptr1) add_fixup(&ptr1->prev);
else    add_fixup(&ptr2->prev->next);

fprintf(stderr,"Nfix=%u\n", nfix);
for(ifix=0; ifix < nfix; ifix++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%p --> %p\n", fixlist[ifix], *fixlist[ifix]);
        }

        /* Perform the rough swap */
tmp = example.nodes[one];
example.nodes[one] = example.nodes[two];
example.nodes[two] = tmp;

        /* Fixup the pointers, but only if they happen to point at one of the two nodes */
for(ifix=0; ifix < nfix; ifix++) {
        if (*fixlist[ifix] == ptr1) *fixlist[ifix] = ptr2;
        else *fixlist[ifix] = ptr1;
        }
}

void dumpit(char *msg)
{
struct Node *ptr;
int i;

printf("%s\n", msg);
ptr = &example.head;
printf("Head: %p {%p,%p} %d\n", ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next, ptr->val);

for (i=0; i < MAXN; i++) {
        ptr = example.nodes+i;
        printf("# %u # %p {%p,%p} %d\n", i, ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next, ptr->val);
        }
}

int main(void)
{
dumpit("Original");

swapit(1,2);
dumpit("After swap(1,2)");

swapit(0,1);
dumpit("After swap(0,1)");

swapit(0,2);
dumpit("After swap(0,2)");

swapit(0,4);
dumpit("After swap(0,4)");

return 0;
}
```

---

To illustrate the fact that we can ignore the `in_use` condition, here is a new version, with *two* double linked lists present in the same array. This could be an *in_use* list and ad *free* list.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    struct Node *prev, *next;
    // double *_pData;
    // int val;
    char * payload;
        };

#define MAXN 8
struct Example {
    struct Node head;
    struct Node free; /* freelist */
    struct Node nodes[MAXN];
        };

        /* sample data */
struct Example example = {
        { &example.nodes[5] , &example.nodes[0] , ""} /* Head */
        , { &example.nodes[6] , &example.nodes[2] , ""} /* freelist */

/* 0 */ ,{ { &example.head , &example.nodes[1] , "zero"}
        , { &example.nodes[0] , &example.nodes[3] , "one"}
        , { &example.free , &example.nodes[6] , NULL }
        , { &example.nodes[1] , &example.nodes[4] , "two"}
/* 4 */ , { &example.nodes[3] , &example.nodes[5] , "three"}
        , { &example.nodes[4] , &example.head , "four"}
        , { &example.nodes[2] , &example.free , NULL}
        , { &example.nodes[7] , &example.nodes[7] , "OMG"} /* self referenced */
          }
        };

void swapit( unsigned one, unsigned two)
{
struct Node tmp, *ptr1, *ptr2;
        /* *unique* array of pointers-to pointer
         * to fixup all the references to the two moved nodes
         */
struct Node **fixlist[4];
unsigned nfix = 0;
unsigned ifix;

        /* Ugly macro to add entries to the list of fixups */

#define add_fixup(pp) fixlist[nfix++] = (pp)

ptr1 = &example.nodes[one];
ptr2 = &example.nodes[two];

        /* Add pointers to some of the 4 possible pointers to the fixup-array.
        ** If the {prev,next} pointers do not point to {ptr1,ptr2}
        ** we do NOT need to fix them up.
        ** Note: we do not need the tests (.payload == NULL) if the linked lists
        ** are disjunct (such as: a free list and an active list)
        */
if (1||ptr1->payload) { /* This is on purpose: always True */
        if (ptr1->next == ptr2) add_fixup(&ptr2->next); // need &ptr2->next here (instead of ptr1)
        else    add_fixup(&ptr1->next->prev);
        if (ptr1->prev == ptr2) add_fixup(&ptr2->prev); // , because pointer swap takes place AFTER the object swap
        else    add_fixup(&ptr1->prev->next);
        }
if (1||ptr2->payload) { /* Ditto */
        if (ptr2->next == ptr1) add_fixup(&ptr1->next);
        else    add_fixup(&ptr2->next->prev);
        if (ptr2->prev == ptr1) add_fixup(&ptr1->prev);
        else    add_fixup(&ptr2->prev->next);
        }

fprintf(stderr,"Nfix=%u\n", nfix);
for(ifix=0; ifix < nfix; ifix++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%p --> %p\n", fixlist[ifix], *fixlist[ifix]);
        }

        /* Perform the rough swap */
tmp = example.nodes[one];
example.nodes[one] = example.nodes[two];
example.nodes[two] = tmp;

        /* Fixup the pointers, but only if they happen to point at one of the two nodes */
for(ifix=0; ifix < nfix; ifix++) {
        if (*fixlist[ifix] == ptr1) *fixlist[ifix] = ptr2;
        else *fixlist[ifix] = ptr1;
        }
}

void dumpit(char *msg)
{
struct Node *ptr;
int i;

printf("%s\n", msg);
ptr = &example.head;
printf("Head: %p {%p,%p} %s\n", ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next, ptr->payload);
ptr = &example.free;
printf("Free: %p {%p,%p} %s\n", ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next, ptr->payload);

for (i=0; i < MAXN; i++) {
        ptr = example.nodes+i;
        printf("# %u # %p {%p,%p} %s\n", i, ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next, ptr->payload);
        }
}

int main(void)
{
dumpit("Original");

swapit(1,2); /* these are on different lists */
dumpit("After swap(1,2)");

swapit(0,1);
dumpit("After swap(0,1)");

swapit(0,2);
dumpit("After swap(0,2)");

swapit(0,4);
dumpit("After swap(0,4)");

swapit(2,5); /* these are on different lists */
dumpit("After swap(2,5)");

return 0;
}
```